# Matching elements in an index matrix with elements in another matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matching

I have a matrix,

```
A=[1 3 4 
   3 1 5 
 NaN 3 6]
```

and another index matrix, with the first column as index and the second containing values which I would like to use to replace the matching indices in A.

```
B=[ 1 333
    2 356
    3 112
    4 789
    5 762
    6 221
    7 876
    8 922 ]
```

I want to match the elements in matrix A with the corresponding index (1st column) in matrix B and return (except for the NaN values

```
C= [333 112 789
    112 333 762
    NaN 112 221]
```

It is easy in Matlab but as I am transitioning into Python. I am a bit confused with how to approach it. (Please see the code for the same in Matlab in the comments).

Comment: [idx,idy] = ismember(A,B(:,1));
C = nan(size(A));
C(idx) = B(idy(idx),2)